# How to solve Permutation of a phone number problem

Tags: c++, permutation

The Problem:

A company is distributing phone numbers to its employees to make things easier. the next digit cannot be equal to the last is the only rule for example 0223 is not allowed while 2023 is allowed. At least three digits will be excluded every time. Write a function that takes in a length of the phone number and the digits that will be excluded. The function should print all possible phone numbers.

I got this question in an interview and I have seen one like it before at my university. It is a permutation problem. My question is what is the best way or decent way to solve this without a million for loops.

I do understand that this is technically how it works

length of phone number = 3;

[0-9], [0-9] excluding the last digit, [0-9] excluding the last digit

but I am unsure on how the best way to turn this into code. Any language is accepted!

thank you:

Also I might be asking this in the wrong place. please let me know if I am.

Comment: Perhaps you could write a recursive procedure? Have you learned this technique yet?

Comment: i tried a recursive function in the interview, but my brain failed.

Comment: Ah, sorry about that. A way you could do this without recursion, though, could maybe just involve iterating through all integers from 0 to 10^(number of digits) - 1, and test each number. For example, when the length of the phone number is 3, you could iterate from 0 to 999, and notice how every number corresponds to a unique 3-digit phone number sequence (and every phone number sequence corresponds to one of those 3-digit numbers). Then, just test every individual number.

Comment: I kind of did this as well. I made a variable that held the value 10^lengthOfNum and I did while(i < totalPhoneNums) @Telescope but thats as far as I got lol

Comment: In that case, did anything go wrong with that approach? Did you have any specific problems?

Comment: I wasn't sure how to generate a phone number with each number. like if i = 0 the first number would be 010 next would be 012, 013, 014 etc but I couldn't figure out how to generate that. My brain went blank

Comment: It's not a permutation problem. It's a combinatorial one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to solve this problem could be using Recursion. Here's my commented C++ code:

```cpp
void solve(int depth, int size, vector <int> &curr_seq){

    // If the recursion depth is equal to size, that means we've decided size
    // numbers, which means that curr_seq.size() == size. In other words, we've
    // decided enough numbers at this point to create a complete phone number, so
    // we print it and return.

    if(depth == size){
        for(int item : curr_seq){
            cout << item;
        }
        cout << "\n";

        return;
    }

    // Try appending every possible digit to the current phone number
    for(int i = 0; i <= 9; ++i){

        // Make sure to only append the digit i if it is not equal to the last digit
        // of the phone number. We can also append it, however, if curr_seq
        // is empty (because that means that we haven't decided the 1st digit yet).
        if(curr_seq.empty() || curr[curr.size() - 1] != i){
            curr_seq.push_back(i);
            solve(depth + 1, size, curr);
            curr_seq.pop_back();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How would you run this function initially? just an empty arr?

Comment: I got it, is the depth like the place the value is on like if its 3 it would be on _ _ _ <- the last space

Comment: @devin Yes, that is correct. `depth` refers to the recursion depth of `solve()`, which means it also represents how many numbers we have decided at the moment (how many numbers are in `curr_seq`).

Comment: I am marking this as the correct answer as it does work, but I am unsure how curr_seq knows how to seperate each number. Heres how the program works step by step for me when it reaches the for loop. I will check if its empty or if the digit previously is not the same as the digit now. It will then append this digit and push this to the array so the first will be 0. then it will run the function again in the next place so if it was a size of 3 it would be in the tens place. or in the middle. Heres where it gets confusing. its going to append 1 to 0 so the array is {0,1}

Comment: My question @Telescope is it is using the same vector every time that it runs the same function again so shouldn't it be 0123456789 repeating 3 times? how does it know to stop at the third digit in the string?

Comment: @devin Notice that after we return from recursing, the next line is `curr_seq.pop_back()`. This is standard for many recursive procedures; it basically represents "returning" to the current state by removing the values we added during the recursion. What this does is it makes sure that we don't do any extra appending, so curr_seq will *not* just be `0123456789` repeating 3 times.

Answer (score 0):

I think I like the recursive solution, but you can also just generate all permutations up to the limit (iterate), filter out any with repeating digits, and print the successful candidates:

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

// Because C/C++ still has no integer power function.
int ipow(int base, int exp) {
    int result = 1;
    for (;;) {
        if (exp & 1)
            result *= base;
        exp >>= 1;
        if (!exp)
            return result;
        base *= base;
    }
}

void noconsec(const int len) {
    int lim = ipow(10, len);

    // For e.g. len 4 (lim 10000),
    // obviously 00xx won't work, so skip anything smaller than lim / 100.
    int start = (len <= 2) ? 0 : (lim / 100);

    for (int num = start;num < lim;num++) {
        // Convert to string.
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << std::setw(len) << std::setfill('0') << num;
        std::string num_s = ss.str();

        // Skip any consecutive digits.
        bool is_okay = true;
        auto prev_digit = num_s[0];
        for (int digit_idx = 1;digit_idx < num_s.length();digit_idx++) {
            auto digit = num_s[digit_idx];
            if (prev_digit == digit) {
                is_okay = false;
            }
            prev_digit = digit;
        }

        // Output result.
        if (is_okay) {
            cout << num_s << "\n";
        }
    }
}

int main(const int argc, const char * const argv[]) {
    noconsec(4);
}
```

Differences to note, this needs an integer power function to compute the limit. Converting an int to a string and then checking the string is more complex than constructing the string directly. I guess it could be useful if you have a list of integers already, but mostly I did it for fun.